# Android studio layout inspector doesn't work for emulator API <= 17

Tags: android, android-studio, layout-inspector

I am using android studio, i run the app, in android monitor section,  i click "layout inspector" button, i am getting this message

***Capture view hierarchy*** : Unable to obtain list of windows used by "my app name"

I already tried with Android emulator api level 16, 17, i am getting the above.
For emulators api >=18, things work as expected.

Is there something wrong with my setup, cause i find nothing document the specific behavior i am getting.

Thanks

Comment: Hi! Any news about this issue? Layout inspector doesn't work for me also with API 19 ... the error is "Error obtaining view hierarchy: Unexpected error: empty view hierarchy"

Comment: What exactly are you trying to capture? A view with Google Maps for instance?

Answer (score 0):

It just doesn't work.

If you update Android Studio and try again, it will already show a better error message:

`Layout inspector requires device API version to be 18 or greater.`